# Determing $a_1^{-1}+a_2^{-1}-a_3^{-1}-a_4^{-1}+\cdots$ from $a_1^{-1}-a_2^{-1}+a_3^{-1}-a_4^{-1}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a way of determining

> $\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\dfrac{1}{a_2}-\dfrac{1}{a_3}-\dfrac{1}{a_4}+\cdots$

if you know the alternating series

> $\dfrac{1}{a_1}-\dfrac{1}{a_2}+\dfrac{1}{a_3}-\dfrac{1}{a_4}+\cdots$

?

Both series are assumed to be convergent.

Comment: $a_n$ is known?

Comment: @the_candyman Does that matter? In the example I was given, $a_n =$ was odd cubes, but I thought it would be easier if there was a general proof.

Comment: I just asked to understand if there are other additional information.

Comment: It is unclear. More information is needed on the first series.. what is it exactly?

Comment: It is not unclear. The question is perfectly clear. And the answer is, "no, definitely not in general."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for example, $a_{2n} = a_{2n-1}$ for all positive integers $n$, your second sum (assuming it converges) is $0$, but the first is $2/a_1 - 2/a_3 + 2/a_5 - \ldots$ which could be anything.

Comment: I take it it only works in special cases then, thanks!